# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [559, 140]

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Here's the code below...  I dont know what's wrong with my code. plz help. the error is occured in line 
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing, neighbors
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 

df = pd.read_csv('breast-cancer-wisconsin.txt')
df.replace('?', -99999, inplace=True)
df.drop(['id'], 1, inplace=True)    

X = np.array(df.drop(['class'],1)) 
y = np.array(df['class'])

X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test = 
train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.2)

clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()

print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

accuracy = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print (accuracy)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your **X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test = 
train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.2)** part.

According to scikit-learn documentation in [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html),the correct order of return value of **train_test_split** function is:

- X_train,
- X_test,
- y_train,
- y_test

Your order in the code is wrong. Let's replace the line you have used ** train_test_split** with this line:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.2)
```

Hopefully, this will resolve your issue.